# Problem with function arguments in R

Tags: r

I wrote a function that takes 2 parameters , but calling the function with specific values raises an error message. Here's my code:

```
dynamicwilcox <- function(column, datacol) {    
    t = read.table("all.txt")
    #print(column)
    if(column=="Ph") {
        uniphy=unique(c(t$Phylum))
        print(uniphy)
    }               

    if(column=="Cl") {
        uniclass = unique(c(t$Class))
        print(uniclass)
    }   
}
```

Calling the function`dynamicwilcox("Ph","A")` gives me an error. Why?

Comment: @lecodesportif : unexpected symbol in " dynamicwilcox("Ph" 
but when i try to run it like this  : dynamicwilcox(Ph,A) it does not give me error , but the script won't print anything.

Comment: @lecodesportif: thnx for your help , i found out the problem , i was missing a " inside the function , but i tried to add a varaible that can be read from the keyboard and let the function work based on it , but it's not working , can you help me ??

Comment: @coffeetocode: thnx for your help ,i found out the problem , i was missing a " inside the function , but i tried to add a varaible that can be read from the keyboard and let the function work based on it , but it's not working , can you help me ??

Comment: @abd see `?readline` - I'll edit my answer below with an example - but do note this will only work if you are interacting with R - i.e. you have it running in a console or the R GUI for example, but not in batch mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something strange is certainly going on - was that all of the error message?

If I take your code back to basics and comment out all the stuff I can't run because I don't have your data file, the following function works without error:

```
dynamicwilcox <- function(column,datacol) {   
    ##dat <- read.table("all.txt") ## probably not good to call something t
    if(column=="Ph") {
        ##uniphy=unique(c(t$Phylum))
        ##print(uniphy)
        writeLines("column was 'Ph'")
    }
    if(column=="Cl") {
        ##uniclass = unique(c(t$Class))
        ##print(uniclass)
        writeLines("column was 'Cl'")
    }
}

R> dynamicwilcox("Ph", "A")
column was 'Ph'
```

Perhaps you could start with the above code and see if it works for you, and if it does, build upon it.

As for `dynamicwilcox(Ph, A)` working, it can't work unless you have already defined objects `Ph` and `A` in your current environment. It won't print anything because whatever is stored **in** `Ph` is **not** equal to `"Ph"` or `"Cl"`. What do you get if you run these two lines ?:

```
R> Ph
R> A
```

Hopefully that will explain why that way of calling your function failed.

**Update:** As for altering the function to use `readline()` so it accepts user input, here is one version:

```
dynamicwilcox <- function() {
    ANSWER <- readline("What column do you want to work on? ")
    if(ANSWER=="Ph") {
        writeLines("column was 'Ph'")
    } else if(ANSWER=="Cl") {
        writeLines("column was 'Cl'")
    } else {
        writeLines(paste("Sorry, we don't know what to do with column", ANSWER))
    }
    ANSWER ## return something
}
```

Here it is in use:

```
R> dynamicwilcox()
What column do you want to work on? Ph
column was 'Ph'
[1] "Ph"
R> dynamicwilcox()
What column do you want to work on? Cl
column was 'Cl'
[1] "Cl"
R> dynamicwilcox()
What column do you want to work on? FooBar
Sorry, we don't know what to do with column FooBar
[1] "FooBar"
```

But do read `?readline` as it has something just like this in one of the examples that you could learn from.

Comment: @Gavin Simpson: thnx for your help , but i found out the error ,i was missng a ", and this worked :dynamicwilcox("Ph", "A") , but now i'm trying to read from keyboard , and execute the script based on what i read , i asked a new question for this , and you helped me :) but i did not found the complete solution , because the scan did not worked in my case

Comment: @abd I've updated to show how to use `readline()` and I have just left another comment on your earlier Q about reading from the keyboard.

Comment: @Gavin Simpson: Hello , i did tried this but it didn't worked, the script is not waiting me to enter the word , it just continue :| , i'm running the script on windows and result appear on a DOS.is this the error ??

Comment: @adb **How** many times do we have to tell you that you can't run in BATCH mode *and* use `readline()`!!! Open R GUI on your Windows box. Then run `source(file.choose()` and select your script in the dialogue that appears. There `readline()` will work. Please do read the answers we provide - it will save a lot of frustration on both our parts...

Comment: @adb sorry, typo in the above comment. It should have been `source(file.choose())` there was a missing closing parenthesis.